# Search and sort documents based on weights assigned to tags

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am looking for an alternative for Tag based search in mongodb which could perform well in a heavy traffic application (atleast 100 req/sec)

Below is an example of the docs. 
**Doc1**

```
"unique_id": "cOxmb8",
"name":"Jon Snow",
"knows":"Nothing",
"height":173,
"tags": [
  "leader",
  "king in the north",
  "stark",
  "CastleBlack"]
```

**Doc2**

```
"unique_id": "qxbf0d",
"name":"Samwell Tarly",
"knows":"Everything",
"height":172,
"tags": [
  "insightful",
  "sam the slayer",
  "tarly",
  "CastleBlack"]
```

Collection has 900k docs. Backend api is in golang.
If I search for "CastleBlack insightful leader" both docs would match 2 tags. But I want "Samwell Tarly" to show up first. The results should be optimized for high traffic application.

I achieved this by assigning weights dynamically to the search string in my api and sorting them on the sum of the weights. Below is the pipeline I used in my aggregation.

```
CastleBlack := 3,
insightful := 2,
leader := 1


[{"$match":
    {"root_words":{"$all":["CastleBlack"]}},
    {"root_words":{"$all":["insightful"]}},
    {"root_words":{"$all":["leader"]}}
},
{"$project":
    {
    "unique_id":0,
    "name":1,
    "knows":1,
    "weight":
        {"$add":[ 
            {"$multiply":[{"$size":{"$setIntersection":["$root_words",["CastleBlack"]]}},3]},
            {"$multiply":[{"$size":{"$setIntersection":["$root_words",["insightful"]]}},2]},
            {"$multiply":[{"$size":{"$setIntersection":["$root_words",["leader"]]}},1]}
        ]}

    }
},
{"$sort":
    {
        "weight": -1,
    }

}
]
```

I used $all instead of $in because $in didn't perform well under load test(100 req/sec). Full text search is of no use in heavy traffic applications. Is there any better way to achieve this and possibly optimize and make the query faster?

Comment: why would you want the Samwell Tarly to show up first in the result even though both of the document match 2 tags?

Comment: Aim here is to show most relevant results. As "insightful" is the second word in the search string, Samwell Tarly would be more relevant